# How to serialize gensim corpus in pyspark using apache-zeppelin notebook?

Tags: hadoop, serialization, pyspark, gensim, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to create a gensim corpus and save it to arbitrary HDFS or regular FS path. I am using pyspark (2.2.1) and running a zeppelin notebook on a hadoop cluster. Here is my minimal example:

```
from gensim import corpora
import os

path = "/my/existing/hadoop/path"
corpus = [[(0,0), (1,2)]]
corpora.MmCorpus.serialize(os.path.join(path,"corpus.mm"), corpus)
```

This leads to error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/my/existing/hadoop/path/corpus.mm'
```

Although the path exists.

Running the following works.

```
corpora.MmCorpus.serialize("corpus.mm", corpus)
corpora.MmCorpus.serialize(os.path.join("/tmp","corpus.mm"), corpus)
```

However, I can't find it. I checked `/tmp` and `hadoop fs -ls /tmp`
What kind of path is required when working with pyspark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What kind of path is required when working with pyspark?

Regular path is required when saving regular paths.
It is only necessary to ensure that zeppelin has rights to write to the required location. You also have to know which node of the cluster is the current session running on.

> Running the following works.
>
> corpora.MmCorpus.serialize("corpus.mm", corpus)
>      corpora.MmCorpus.serialize(os.path.join("/tmp","corpus.mm"), corpus)

Location can be found simply by

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```